# Ошибка при работе Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_scripts_method' not found or invalid function name in D:\OSPanel\domains\cardboard\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Comment: У вас хук неправильно описан. Покажите объявления add_filter() и add_action(), которые вы добавили.

Comment: У меня та же история: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_scripts_method' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/u0477897/data/www/mehmos.ru/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286 А как правильно описать хук и где эти объявления?

Comment: Если вы видите ошибку, у вас и трассировка должна быть показана, вплоть до вызова apply_filter() или do_action(). Вот и смотрите, какой фильтр или действие там вызываются, а потом ищите у себя, где они объявлены.

Comment: Я вижу сообщение на главной и всех страницах сайта, но трассировки не вижу - как ее посмотреть?

Comment: Включите вывод отладочной информации средствами WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress или установите плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-php-console/ , он выведет информацию в консоль браузера, что более удобно.